# Bulk download of certain files from a GitHub repo

Tags: linux, git, github

Is it possible to bulk/sequentially download all of the `*.tar.gz` from a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/GloriousEggroll/proton-ge-custom/releases)? Instead of manually downloading everything, is it possible to do so using a certain command or would I have to create a script? I'm using Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first consider simply cloning the repository with `git`, it's then easier to do comparisons between releases. That's out of the scope of this Q/A.

I present two methods: a web-based approach, and a GitHub specific approach using an API:

### Web scraping

Here's a quick-n-dirty one-liner script (split here into multiple lines for some readability), requiring `w3m`, `awk`, `xargs` and `curl`. This ad hoc script is probably not meant to be used within anything automated.

- using `w3m` to format the page contents with all links at the end,
- `awk` to extract only the links including the string `/releases/download/` and ending with `.tar.gz` in their URL,
- `xargs` to convert output into command line parameters to feed to
- `curl` to download them. It's even suitable for n parallel downloads by adding `-P n` to `xargs`:

.

```
w3m -o display_link_number=1 -dump https://github.com/GloriousEggroll/proton-ge-custom/releases | 
    awk '$1 ~ /\[[0-9]+\]/ && $2 ~ /\/releases\/download\/.*\.tar\.gz$/ { print $2 }' | 
    xargs -n 1 curl -JRLO
```

inserting `echo` before `curl` to prevent the download to actually happen outputs this:

```
curl -JRLO https://github.com/GloriousEggroll/proton-ge-custom/releases/download/6.10-GE-1/Proton-6.10-GE-1.tar.gz
curl -JRLO https://github.com/GloriousEggroll/proton-ge-custom/releases/download/6.9-GE-2-github-actions-test/Proton-6.9-GE-2-github-actions-test.tar.gz
curl -JRLO https://github.com/GloriousEggroll/proton-ge-custom/releases/download/6.9-GE-2/Proton-6.9-GE-2.tar.gz
curl -JRLO https://github.com/GloriousEggroll/proton-ge-custom/releases/download/6.9-GE-1/Proton-6.9-GE-1.tar.gz
curl -JRLO https://github.com/GloriousEggroll/proton-ge-custom/releases/download/6.8-GE-2/Proton-6.8-GE-2.tar.gz
curl -JRLO https://github.com/GloriousEggroll/proton-ge-custom/releases/download/6.8-GE-1/Proton-6.8-GE-1.tar.gz
```

note: the `-o display_link_number=1` option isn't really documented but appears as example in [`w3m`'s man page](https://manpages.debian.org/w3m/w3m.1#Filter-like_usage).

This will be limited to the contents of the first page, so won't make all downloads available. As the next page link requires to know the contents (specifically the last displayed release in the page), handling this would get too complex.

Better use the...

### GitHub REST API

There's a [GitHub API related to releases](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#releases) that doesn't appear to require any credential for this task and outputs its results in JSON format, suitable for script processing with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) (it's usually available as distribution package). This requires `curl`, `xargs`, `jq`. `jq` will display the download URL for every assets' name ending in `.tar.gz`. (Examining first the initial *curl* dump with `| jq .` allows to find the useful parts).

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' 'https://api.github.com/repos/GloriousEggroll/proton-ge-custom/releases' | 
    jq -r '
        .[].assets[] | if .name | endswith(".tar.gz") then
            .browser_download_url
        else
            empty
        end' | 
    xargs -n 1 curl -JRLO
```

Inserting `echo` before the last `curl` will give the same output as in the first method, except there will be 30 of them instead of ~ 6.

As [described in the API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#releases), *per_page* defaults to 30. Adding to the URL `?per_page=XX` can go up to 100 results. Anything bigger would need a loop with also the additional parameter `&page=Y` and detecting when it ends.

Comment: Wow! Very thorough answer. Thanks a lot!